# How to install RevKit

Tags: bash, python, software-installation, scripts, compiling

I’m trying to install a software called RevKit on Ubuntu 12.10 and the following instructions<sup>**1**</sup> need to be followed:

> RevKit can be downloaded from the www.revkit.org website. Opening a
>   Bash shell and assuming that the file revkit-1.3.tar.gz is in the
>   current working directory, first the package needs to be unpacked:
>
> ```
> tar xvfz revkit−1.3.tar . gz
> cd revkit−1.3
> ```
>
> Then, you can build the toolkit. The build process is divided into two
>   scripts. First, the RevKit environment is created using the bootstrap
>   script. Afterwards, the RevKit algorithms are built using the build
>   script. This has the benefit of running the second script only if
>   changes have been made on the algorithms but not on the environment.
>   The bootstrap script should only be called once at the beginning. More
>   precisely, first run the bootstrap script:
>
> ```
> ./make.py bootstrap
> ```
>
> This will download and compile all dependencies automatically. For
>   that purpose, compiling boost takes some time. If you already have
>   installed boost using the distribution’s package manager, the option
>   `-DBOOST PATH` can be used to specify its path, e.g. `-DBOOST PATH=/usr`. 
>   Alternatively you can specify the boost include and libs
>   path separately by using `–boost`, `–boost-include-dir` and
>   `–boost-lib-dir` as arguments. Please make sure that your version of
>   boost satisfies the requirements. After bootstrapping the environment,
>   the build script needs to be executed. To run this script manually
>   call:
>
> ```
> ./make.py build
> ```
>
> This will build the whole RevKit suite including the core, algorithms,
>   examples, and the Python bindings. The Python bindings enable the CLI
>   to use RevKit like a shell. If the system cannot build the Python
>   bindings or if they are not needed, they can be deactivated by
>   calling:
>
> ```
> ./make.py build −DBUILD BINDINGS=OFF
> ```
>
> instead. Further packages which are not available in the distribution’s package
>   manager (e.g. CUDD or PUMA) are downloaded and installed automatically
>   from the bootstrap script. Boost is also required and will be
>   downloaded and installed by default.
>
> The build script must be called at least once. Afterwards, the sources
>   only need to be compiled again if local changes have been performed.
>   Alternatively, the program make can be executed manually by calling:
>
> ```
> make
> ```
>
> in the build directory. The build script also provides the options of
>   enabling and disabling the compilation of unstable and example
>   algorithms by using the parameters `-DBUILD UNSTABLE` and `-DBUILD EXAMPLES`.

if this is correct an gui window should open in the following instructions which am not able to see:

4.1. RevKit Graphical User Interface
The RevKit Graphical User Interface enables the creation and execution of customized
design processes to be executed. Therefore, a GUI is utilized where the respective tasks
can easily be put together by means of item blocks connected to a graph. Each item
performs an operation and may have ports for the respective input parameters and
output results. Input ports can be connected to output ports forming a channel when
they support the same data types.
In order to start the RevKit Graphical User Interface, the following command has to
be invoked from within the root directory of RevKit:

> ./tools/gui/gui.py

I was able to do the first 2 instructions, but after that I am unable to follow what has to be done, i.e. the instructions relating to the bootstrap script. Can anyone tell me what exactly needs to be done? basically i need to get to the gui interface which am unable to do

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>[RevKit – User Manual, 3. Download and Installation](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/revkit/revkit_user_manual.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Why are you unable to follow the instructions? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: yup nothing happens on running the first make command @karel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install some essential files requires for compiling software and downloading the dependencies. You can install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
```

If this doesn't work, please specify the output you get when running the make line.

Comment: here m uploading a pic:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LesTcmHNFybE1jMnVZcm10a1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok how do i do that? is there a command line?

Comment: did that....there is no change in the execution of make commands

Comment: is it possible that the make commands might be working? although it isn't showing anything on the terminal after their execution??

Comment: i have added an edit to the question. if anyone can get to the gui part it would be most helpful

Comment: I downloaded revkit and installed it on a vanilla install of 14.04 with build-essentials installed. I got **lots** of output on the make.py commands. I guess I can't help you any further, sorry.

Comment: i tried it again n got some output this time....maybe u can help now....below are d pics for it...plzzzz help:  
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-LesTcmHNFyWFFjam56SkQxUzA&usp=sharing

Comment: As the output says, you need git. I updated my answer to reflect that. Without git the dependencies won't download which leads to all the other errors you have. When you post output messages in the future, use a paste service lile http://paste.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: ok so i installed git as u told above n then redid the whole thing....at the end of the execution of the first make statement it gave me this output....is it correct? or do i need to install something else?
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7466323/

Comment: No, you need to *Install the packages containing the above header files to compile boost properly.* as the output states. You can search for these files on packages.ubuntu.com (the second search field). You have to install some -dev packages to get these header files. In this case I would say you need libbz2-dev and zlib1g-dev. Just read the output and follow the instructions. **failed** usually means it didn't work ;-)

Comment: i actually installed both those packages after posting the comment....still the process isn't working. please check this out:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7466799/

Comment: Have you started fresh from the beginning (deleting everything you tried before). Because at the beginning the script pulls in boost as a dependency, but your output looks like it assumes boost is already present.

Comment: i tried from scratch but i'm still getting this error in the bootstrap command:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7540703/

Comment: problem resolved....check out the comments at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/482738/getting-error-in-opening-py-file

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal So how did you resolve the problem? Lets leave the result here so that others can find it.

Comment: ran these $ commands:
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake python-dev ipython python-qt4 python-numpy

sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0 libbz2-dev libbz2-ocaml libbz2-ocaml-dev

sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

sudo apt-get install build-essential git


and after that you had to go into the file gui.py and remove the algorithms related to unstable....5-6 lines... and then give the command the gui interface opens up :)

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal that was my question. What exactly did you change? which lines did you remove?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [libboost-all-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libboost-all-dev) installed?

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Now try following those steps again.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fulfill the requirements:

1. git (`sudo apt-get install git`)
2. clang (`sudo apt-get install clang`)
3. c++ (`sudo apt-get install build-essential`)
4. boost (`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`)